# Access components props which is returned from HOC - Jest with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

I am trying to write test cases for my `hoc`, which i call in another `hoc`. The code looks like:

**`getData.jsx`**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function getData(Receiver) {

    function fetchData(props) {
        const [dataInState, setData] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
            loadData();
        }, []); 

        const loadData = () => {
            const { ids = [], data: existingData = [] } = props;    // existing data from redux store
            if(ids.length) {
                if(existingData.length) {
                    setData([...existingData]);    
                }
                else {
                    // fetching data from actions
                    setData([...dataFromActions]);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("in else")
            }
        }

        return (<Receiver data={dataInState} {...props} />);
    }

    const mapStateToProps = ({ router, dataFromStore }) => {
        const { data = [] } = dataFromStore;
        return {
            router,
            data,
        };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
        doGetDataRequest,
    };

    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(fetchData);
}
```

and in my **test file**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import getData from './getData';

let store;

describe('test for hoc', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const mockStore = configureStore();

        // creates the store with any initial state or middleware needed
        store = mockStore({
            ...
        });
    });

    it('Should render the component ', () => {
        configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
        const ids = [];
        const Component = <h1 ids={ids}>Hola</h1>;
        const ConditionalHOC = getData(Component);
        // read props here somewhere
        const wrapper = shallow(<ConditionalHOC store={store} />);
        expect(wrapper).not.toBe(null);
    });
});
```

the test case runs successfully. However i want's to get the props from the component which is returned from `HOC` i.e data which is calculated and passed from `hoc` file.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create test utility function to render HOC children

```js
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

const render = (hoc, props, context) => {
    const Component = () => <div />
    const WrappedComponent = hoc(Component)
    return mount(<WrappedComponent {...props} />, { context })
}

export default (hoc, props, context) => {
  const component = render(hoc, props, context)
    const update = () => {
        component.update()
        return component.find('Component')
    }
    return {
        component: component.find('Component'),
        update,
        root: component,
    }
}
```

2. Then use it like this

```js
import renderHOC from 'your/path'
it('your test', () => {
        const {component} = renderHOC(yourHOC, props)
        expect(component.prop('propName')).toBe(expected)
        component.prop('anotherProp')() // runs state update in HOC
        expect(component.update().prop('updatedProp')).toBe(expected) // NB `update()` is required if you are updating state of the HOC
    })
```